# Pushing to empty array set as initial value in empty array in reduce

Tags: javascript

When reduce is performed on an empty array with an empty array set as its initial value, apparently a value can't be pushed to that initial empty array (pushing isn't possible), whereas it can when reduce is performed on an array with a null value. Why doesn't it work in the first scenario without the null value?

Why doesn't `[]` set as the initial value (the [second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#parameters) of reduce) count as an element?
For example, you can perform reduce on an empty array with 0 set as the initial value:
`[].reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0) // 0`

```js
[].reduce((arr, curr) => {
    arr.push('val')
    return arr
}, []);
// []
```

```js
[null].reduce((arr, curr) => {
    arr.push('val')
    return arr
}, []);
// ['val']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first reduce is working as intended. As it is already reduced it will not perform anything.

To be more explicit, the callback you pass to the `reduce()` method will be called on each element of the array, but as your array is empty, there it will not be called.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce.

Comment: Please see updated question. Why doesn't [] set as the initial value (the second parameter of reduce) count as an element?

Comment: You set `[]` as initial value of the accumulator, and then for each element of the empty array (so, none) it will apply the reduction function, in total 0 amount of times. In that case your result is equal to the initial value.

Answer (score 1):

An empty array have no element, so it dose not run reduce function.
But [null] array has one element 'null'. So this array run reduce function.

Comment: Please see updated question. Why doesn't [] set as the initial value (the second parameter of reduce) count as an element?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs:

> The reduce() method executes a user-supplied “reducer” callback function on each element of the array

If there are no elements the callback won't run

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Please see updated question. Why doesn't [] set as the initial value (the second parameter of reduce) count as an element?